# How to extend JavaScript construtor functions with arguments?

Tags: javascript

I'm used to extend JavaScript constructor functions ('classes') as it described, for example, [here in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). But I've got a problem if parent constructor takes an argument:

```js
function Parent(arg){
    for(var i in arg){
        // do some stuff
    }
}

function Descendant(arg1, arg2) {
    Parent.call(this, arg1);
    // do some more stuff
}
Descendant.prototype = new Parent();// problems starts from here...
```

As you can see when we set prototype we call Parent() without any arguments. And it causes exception, because argument is necessary for Parent. Now I always check if argument provided and exit parent constructor if not. But it looks not very pretty. So I'm interesting if there are some best practice for such cases.

Comment: What's wrong with `if(!arguments.length) return false`?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just wondered if there are any other approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally handle this by passing an object with the arguments or configuration and then conditionally assigning them:

```
function Parent(config){
    if(config){
        this.a = (config.a) ? config.a: "";
        this.b = (config.b) ? config.b: "";
    }
}

function Descendant(config) {
    Parent.call(this, config);
    // do some more stuff
}

Descendant.prototype = new Parent();

var d = new Descendant({a: "something"});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/EfP9B/

Comment: For completeness please do not create a Parent instance to set prototype part of the inheritance. Object.create with a polyfill will be better. All of Parent instance variables end up in the Child and are immediately shadowed when doing `Parent.call(this, config);` There are cases when setting up inheritance an instance of Parent can't be created without spoofing data that isn't available yet and one must over complicate code to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that there's a basic logical issue here: if you've got a constructor that uses one or more arguments to control how it initializes a new object, then that means that the constructor can create some number of variations of objects. Therefore, if you want to use an object created by that constructor as the prototype for another constructor, you're going to have to choose which variation you want. That then means that when you construct the prototype object, you have to decide what parameters to pass to the parent constructor.

JavaScript inheritance is really quite different from inheritance in languages like Java or C++.  There are some cosmetic ways of making it *seem* similar, but ultimately it's JavaScript and not any other language. Specifically, JavaScript inheritance is not about extending constructor functions. Rather, it's about establishing the prototype chain to determine the availability of object properties for constructed objects.  The code inside the constructor function doesn't have anything to do (directly, anyway) with inheritance; it's just code. It may affect object properties, and it may be written with some assumptions about the prototype chain, but it's not inherently bound up with the mechanism of inheritance.